# Mean stack app with Webpack: unable to show image with CSS background-image property

Tags: html, css, angular, webpack, sass

I'm learning by making my own projects and currently I am designing my own MEAN-stack app. This app uses Webpack and in the past I was unable to show any images.
Then I installed a URL-loader and now I am able to show images when I enter the local URL in the src attribute of an img element.

However, now I am trying to use a local image for a background-image property in SCSS and it is not showing at all. The code below shows the SCSS code, HTML code and what I have in my Webpack file. What do I need to do to fix this?

SCSS file: profile-nav.component.SCSS

```
@import "../../SASS/abstracts/variables";
@import "../../SASS/abstracts/mixins";

.img-container {
  height: 33.3333vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("../../images/slytherin-logo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;

  img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    @include center-horizontal-vertical;
    height: 80%;
    width: 25%;


  }
}
```

HTML file: profile-nav.component.html. I am able to show the img image, but not the background image I entered in the SCSS file

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="../../images/profile_picture.jpg" alt="jooo">
</div>
```

Webpack: webpack.config.ts

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: { limit: 40000 }
                    },
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    }
};
```

**EDIT** this is what my webpack.config file looks like after adjustments

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' ] // <------
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] // <-----
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing some loaders:

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' ] // <------
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/, 
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] // <-----
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: { limit: 40000 }
                    },
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but it still doesn't show after I made the adjustments you proposed.

Comment: instead of url-loader try file-loader there

Comment: Still not showing. To be sure I did what you asked me, I added the current state of my webpack.config to the original post.